# Helm upgrade custom microservice causes temporary downtime

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

during deployment of new version of application sequentially 4 pods are terminated and replaced by newer ones; but for those ~10minutes the app is hitting other microservice is hitting older endpoints causing 502/404 errors - anyone know of a way to deploy 4 new pods, then drain traffic from old ones to new ones and after all connections to prev ver are terminated, then terminate the old pods ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably means you don't have a readiness probe set up? Because the default is already to only roll 25% of the pods at once. If you have a readiness probe, this will include waiting until the new pods are actually available and Ready but otherwise it only waits until they start.

Comment: I have readiness probe set for 60 seconds, but the issue is the microservice has to wait for all 4 new pods to deploy before new endpoint is fully available - I wanted to deploy 4 new at once.

Comment: You can change maxSurge to 100%. But I don't think you are correct about how Endpoints work. The Service system tracks on a per-pod level, you don't need all 4 updated at once. The system is designed for safe rolling updates.

Comment: I think what I'm looking for is blue-green deployment implemented, I'll check the maxSurge as well

Comment: Blue green is generally pointless if your probes are set up correctly but you do that by having two deployments with a color label on each, and swap the selector in the service between the two.

Comment: devs are having issues when the new pods are deployed, some endpoint are inaccessible, and some js bundles are downloaded longer than they should with 404 sometimes, everything is fine 10min after update so 99% sure it's the new pods issue with rolling update

Comment: Are you using an ingress perhaps? Those can have desync issues, though it wouldn’t take 10 minutes, usually more like 5-10 seconds.